# Wordpress sub menu not appearing on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

First go at working with a (Dara) child theme here, not far off noob. All was working great and the website was signed off until the client updated Wordpress, and now the submenu items have stopped pulling through on mobile. I tried to use Reponsive Menu plugin as a temporary workaround, but the submenu items do not appear even then.

Had a couple of pals look at it and there appears to be way too much styling applied to .mainnavigation.

Any easy-to-understand help would be much appreciated on my quest to learn Wordpress development!!

Tried deactivating all plugins, doesn't seem to be a conflict. It's gotta be a CSS issue I just don't understand.

Link to site https://froufroudays.co.uk/

Comment: It is a CSS issue you have left: -99999em; in index and  left: 99999em; in style.css. Probably someone tried something that he doesn't understand. Easy way to fix this is just .main-navigation ul ul { position: static; background-color: #154d60; } Suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-navigation appears when parent element is hovered, but the way of this is strange: css change "left" parameter from "99999em" to "1.4em", but only for media query "screen and (min-width: 768px)" - you can find it on the line 2125 of your style.css

So, your theme not expects the sub-navigation in mobile menu.

To resolve this issue you just need to add css rule on hover for media query smaller than 768px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

But this way is not perfect. The best is to show sub-navigation on click on mobile devices using JavaScript.